# How to pass Windows 10 CMD internet traffic through a VPN software?

Tags: windows-10, vpn, cmd.exe, network-traffic

I am using Windscribe free vpn software on Windows 10. But when I use CMD to access some data from the internet it seems it doesn't use my VPN tunnel and tries to access directly to the internet. How can I configure CMD to use Windscribe or any other VPN software that I use?

Comment: The documentation is pretty vague, but it's possible that this requires a Pro license.

Comment: Using a VPN absolutely doesn’t require Windows 10 Professional

Comment: @Ramhound: Using a VPN through CMD needs a Win pro!

Comment: @user3486308 - Since you know that, then you must be running Windows 10 Professional, so that requirement isn't the reason you are having your problem.  Although I still suspect that requirement doesn't actually exist.

Comment: @Ramhound: I think there was a missunderstanding! I use Win10 enterprise. And I can use VPN apps and all my internet traffic will pass through these apps, but CMD connects directly to the internet.and it's traffic wont go through VPN apps and this is what I don't like to be and want to get it through VPN apps as well!

Comment: @user3486308 - I was only responding to a comment I thought contained incorrect information.  I sadly do not have the brain power today, to determine a cause for the behavior you describe, it hasn't been the greatest day.

Comment: @Ramhound: Also it's because of my poor English! What I want to do is connecting CMD to the internet through VPN apps like what other applications, when I start VPN they get their internet traffic through the VPM app that is running. But I don't know why this doesn't happen for CMD and it still connects directly to the internet!